# Do Xcode 15 UIKit views with storyboards work with #Preview macro?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-previews

I'm just trying to get #Preview to work with a UIKit ViewController.
See screenshot for details. Nothing special, IMHO instantiating the VC in the #Preview should just work. But all of the graphical elements that I have in the Main.storyboard don't appear. I just get a white screen.

Is this a general limitation of the macro or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: That would be cool, but I am pretty sure `Previews` are only for SwiftUI views. If you made a `UIRepresentable` for your view controller, you might be able to make it work out, I have never tried though. Let me know if it works!

Comment: @ColdLogic in Xcode 15 Apple made `#Preview` work for UIKit/AppKit as well.

Comment: Oh, thats pretty cool, does it have live updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading the storyboard, just the ViewController. If you want the storyboard content as well you'd need to load it just like you would in actual code, e.g.

```
#Preview {
    UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
}
```

[image: xcode preview of storyboard]

Comment: Thanks @Claus Jørgensen, I could have guessed that, but I didn't :-)
I was hoping the debug constraints in the storyboard this way. But after editing in the storyboard, the preview doesn't update automatically. I need to select the file that contains the preview macro. Anyway, better than nothing.

Comment: @brainray this is a sign from the universe to stop using storyboards :p